# pyspark truncate table without overwrite

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to truncate a table before inserting new data.

I have the following code to insert:

```py
df.write.jdbc(dbUrl, self._loadDb, "append", self._props['dbProps'])
```

Which works great, except.. i want an empty database. I know about setting the mode to overwrite and adding `.option('truncate', True)` but .. this is not what i want.

In another way; how can i execute raw SQL when i want? Without the need for a result `DataFrame`.

I have tried to truncate via `spark.sql`, namely via

```py
spark.sql(f"TRUNCATE TABLE [myDatabase].[stg].[myTable]")
```

this gives me the following error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Executing <class 'jobs.staging.vat.Job'>.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x\spark\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "x\spark\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input '[' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'ANY', 'DISTINCT', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE', 'ROLLUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'AT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'NO', 'EXISTS', 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'NULLS', 'ASC', 'DESC', 'FOR', 'INTERVAL', 'CASE', 'WHEN', 'THEN', 'ELSE', 'END', 'JOIN', 'CROSS', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT', 'SEMI', 'RIGHT', 'FULL', 'NATURAL', 'ON', 'PIVOT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'OVER', 'PARTITION', 'RANGE', 'ROWS', 'UNBOUNDED', 'PRECEDING', 'FOLLOWING', 'CURRENT', 'FIRST', 'AFTER', 'LAST', 'ROW', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'DIRECTORY', 'VIEW', 'REPLACE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'INTO', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 
'FORMAT', 'LOGICAL', 'CODEGEN', 'COST', 'CAST', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'USE', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'DROP', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'TO', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'STRATIFY', 'ALTER', 'RENAME', 'ARRAY', 'MAP', 'STRUCT', 'COMMENT', 'SET', 'RESET', 'DATA', 'START', 'TRANSACTION', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'MACRO', 'IGNORE', 'BOTH', 'LEADING', 'TRAILING', 'IF', 'POSITION', 'EXTRACT', 'DIV', 'PERCENT', 'BUCKET', 'OUT', 'OF', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'OVERWRITE', 'TRANSFORM', 'REDUCE', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'DELIMITED', 'FIELDS', 'TERMINATED', 'COLLECTION', 'ITEMS', 'KEYS', 'ESCAPED', 'LINES', 'SEPARATED', 'FUNCTION', 'EXTENDED', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'LAZY', 'FORMATTED', 'GLOBAL', TEMPORARY, 'OPTIONS', 'UNSET', 'TBLPROPERTIES', 'DBPROPERTIES', 'BUCKETS', 'SKEWED', 'STORED', 'DIRECTORIES', 'LOCATION', 'EXCHANGE', 'ARCHIVE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'FILEFORMAT', 'TOUCH', 'COMPACT', 'CONCATENATE', 'CHANGE', 'CASCADE', 'RESTRICT', 'CLUSTERED', 'SORTED', 'PURGE', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', DATABASE, DATABASES, 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'COMPUTE', 'LIST', 'STATISTICS', 'PARTITIONED', 'EXTERNAL', 'DEFINED', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'REPAIR', 'RECOVER', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD', 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'COMPACTIONS', 'PRINCIPALS', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'LOCKS', 'OPTION', 'ANTI', 'LOCAL', 'INPATH', IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 15)

== SQL ==
TRUNCATE TABLE [myTable].[stg].[MyTable]
---------------^^^
```

Comment: not clear with the question? you can use spark sql.

Comment: I'll edit the q on the error im getting.

Comment: Which database are you connecting for doing the _TRUNCATE_ and loading the dataframe back to the table ?

Comment: the database in question, as inserts are OK, i dont specify a truncate for the DF, thats on the `SparkSession`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this -

For Spark Temp Tables -

```
query = """TRUNCATE TABLE myDatabase.stg.myTable"""
sqlContext.sql(query)
```

For SQL Database Tables -

First create a JDBC connection and truncate the table and then write your dataframe.

Comment: Is this table a spark temp table or sql server ? If this a spark temp table then you can run this query without using brackets[] while specifying table name, if no then you can create a simple JDBC connection to your server and truncate it. Hope it clears.

Comment: I wait to truncate in sql, would your solution be via a different package? That would probably be the case as i think this is not what spark is meant to do.

Comment: Yes, spark can perform queries on its temp tables. Create jdbc for other sql server related use cases. I edited the answer.

Comment: any suggestions for package? Or is there an internal JDBC connection creator for pyspark? I couldnt find it

Comment: You can use JayDeBeApi or pyodbc, I prefer pyodbc for SQL Server.